Can coordinates be immediately captured after mouse modifications in Mathematica 3D graph?
I ask  a question just now. With the reminder from A. Kato, I adopted 3D coordinates. Actually, one of my goals is to convert cylinder graphs into the corresponding TikZ code. However, I'm not completely satisfied with the current coordinates when after converting tikz.
(*A. Kato's code *)
Clear[ptss];
n = 8;
k = 4;

ptss = Table[
   Append[#, i] & /@ CirclePoints[{0, 3}, 3, n], {i, 1, k}];
g = Graph[{UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ ptss, 
    UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ Transpose@ptss} // 
   Flatten, VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[ptss, 1]]


Convert graph g to a TikZ diagram, but some edges overlap, which doesn't look ideal.
generateTikZCodefrom3dgraph[graph_, outputFileName_] := 
 Module[{vertices, coords, edges, maxCoord, numVertices, targetRange, 
   scaleFactor, scaledCoords, tikzCode}, 
   
  (* Extract vertex and coordinate information *)
  vertices = VertexList[graph];  (* List of vertices in the graph *)
  coords = 
   PropertyValue[{graph, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ vertices;  (* Get coordinates of each vertex *)
   
  (* Extract edge information *)
  edges = EdgeList[graph];  (* List of edges in the graph *)
  
  (* Find the maximum absolute value of the coordinates *)
  maxCoord = Max[Abs[coords // N]];  (* Find the maximum absolute value of all coordinates *)
  
  (* Choose target range and scaling factor based on the number of vertices *)
  numVertices = Length[vertices];  (* Get the number of vertices *)
  targetRange = If[numVertices > 20, 10, 5];  (* Choose target range based on vertex count *)
  
  (* Calculate the scaling factor *)
  scaleFactor = targetRange/maxCoord;  (* Calculate scale factor to fit the coordinates in the target range *)
  
  (* If the maximum coordinate value is less than 5, increase the scale factor to expand the range *)
  If[maxCoord < 5, scaleFactor = 10/maxCoord];
  
  (* Apply scaling to the vertex coordinates *)
  scaledCoords = (scaleFactor #) & /@ coords;  (* Scale the coordinates to fit the target range *)
  
  (* Generate the TikZ code for the graph *)
  tikzCode = 
   StringJoin["\\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]\n", 
    StringRiffle[
     Table[ToString[
       TemplateApply[
        "\\node [whitenode] (`v`) at (`x`, `y`, `z`) {};\n", <|
         "v" -> vertices[[i]], "x" -> scaledCoords[[i, 1]], 
         "y" -> scaledCoords[[i, 2]], 
         "z" -> scaledCoords[[i, 3]]|>]], {i, Length[vertices]}], ""],
     StringRiffle[
     Table[ToString[
       TemplateApply[
        "\\draw (`v1`) to (`v2`);\n", <|"v1" -> First[edges[[i]]], 
         "v2" -> Last[edges[[i]]]|>]], {i, Length[edges]}], ""], 
    "\\end{tikzpicture}"];
  
  (* Print the generated TikZ code *)
  Print[tikzCode];
  
  (* Save the generated TikZ code to a file *)
  Export[outputFileName, tikzCode, "Text"];  (* Export the TikZ code as a text file *)
]
generateTikZCodefrom3dgraph[g, "testzlv.tikz"]


I noticed that Mathematica allows us to adjust the 3D plot with the mouse, such as rotating it, but I'm not sure how to obtain the coordinates after the changes. This way, my TikZ diagram will achieve the desired layout with different layout.
tikzcode
\documentclass[tikz, 3d]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d, shapes, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
% Define the 'whitenode' style
\tikzset{
  whitenode/.style={
    draw=black,          % Border color
    fill=white,          % Fill color
    circle,              % Shape of the node
    minimum size=6mm,    % Size of the node
    inner sep=0pt,       % No inner separation between the content and the border
    outer sep=0pt,       % No outer separation
    shading=ball,        % Simple 3D effect using shading
    ball color=white!70, % Ball color with some shading for 3D effect
  }
}

\node [whitenode] (1) at (1.98912, 0.395661,1.73261) {};
\node [whitenode] (2) at (4.80217, 3.20871,1.73261) {};
\node [whitenode] (3) at (4.80217, 7.18695,1.73261) {};
\node [whitenode] (4) at (1.98912, 10.0,1.73261) {};
\node [whitenode] (5) at (-1.98912, 10.0,1.73261) {};
\node [whitenode] (6) at (-4.80217, 7.18695,1.73261) {};
\node [whitenode] (7) at (-4.80217, 3.20871,1.73261) {};
\node [whitenode] (8) at (-1.98912, 0.395661,1.73261) {};
\node [whitenode] (9) at (1.98912, 0.395661,3.46522) {};
\node [whitenode] (10) at (4.80217, 3.20871,3.46522) {};
\node [whitenode] (11) at (4.80217, 7.18695,3.46522) {};
\node [whitenode] (12) at (1.98912, 10.0,3.46522) {};
\node [whitenode] (13) at (-1.98912, 10.0,3.46522) {};
\node [whitenode] (14) at (-4.80217, 7.18695,3.46522) {};
\node [whitenode] (15) at (-4.80217, 3.20871,3.46522) {};
\node [whitenode] (16) at (-1.98912, 0.395661,3.46522) {};
\node [whitenode] (17) at (1.98912, 0.395661,5.19783) {};
\node [whitenode] (18) at (4.80217, 3.20871,5.19783) {};
\node [whitenode] (19) at (4.80217, 7.18695,5.19783) {};
\node [whitenode] (20) at (1.98912, 10.0,5.19783) {};
\node [whitenode] (21) at (-1.98912, 10.0,5.19783) {};
\node [whitenode] (22) at (-4.80217, 7.18695,5.19783) {};
\node [whitenode] (23) at (-4.80217, 3.20871,5.19783) {};
\node [whitenode] (24) at (-1.98912, 0.395661,5.19783) {};
\node [whitenode] (25) at (1.98912, 0.395661,6.93044) {};
\node [whitenode] (26) at (4.80217, 3.20871,6.93044) {};
\node [whitenode] (27) at (4.80217, 7.18695,6.93044) {};
\node [whitenode] (28) at (1.98912, 10.0,6.93044) {};
\node [whitenode] (29) at (-1.98912, 10.0,6.93044) {};
\node [whitenode] (30) at (-4.80217, 7.18695,6.93044) {};
\node [whitenode] (31) at (-4.80217, 3.20871,6.93044) {};
\node [whitenode] (32) at (-1.98912, 0.395661,6.93044) {};
\draw (1) to (2);
\draw (2) to (3);
\draw (3) to (4);
\draw (4) to (5);
\draw (5) to (6);
\draw (6) to (7);
\draw (7) to (8);
\draw (8) to (1);
\draw (9) to (10);
\draw (10) to (11);
\draw (11) to (12);
\draw (12) to (13);
\draw (13) to (14);
\draw (14) to (15);
\draw (15) to (16);
\draw (16) to (9);
\draw (17) to (18);
\draw (18) to (19);
\draw (19) to (20);
\draw (20) to (21);
\draw (21) to (22);
\draw (22) to (23);
\draw (23) to (24);
\draw (24) to (17);
\draw (25) to (26);
\draw (26) to (27);
\draw (27) to (28);
\draw (28) to (29);
\draw (29) to (30);
\draw (30) to (31);
\draw (31) to (32);
\draw (32) to (25);
\draw (1) to (9);
\draw (9) to (17);
\draw (17) to (25);
\draw (2) to (10);
\draw (10) to (18);
\draw (18) to (26);
\draw (3) to (11);
\draw (11) to (19);
\draw (19) to (27);
\draw (4) to (12);
\draw (12) to (20);
\draw (20) to (28);
\draw (5) to (13);
\draw (13) to (21);
\draw (21) to (29);
\draw (6) to (14);
\draw (14) to (22);
\draw (22) to (30);
\draw (7) to (15);
\draw (15) to (23);
\draw (23) to (31);
\draw (8) to (16);
\draw (16) to (24);
\draw (24) to (32);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}



When you rotate 3d graphs with mouse, it only change it's viewpoint not actual coordinates.  You could use Manipulate to manually rotate graph using transformation and copy the coordinate:
coord = GraphEmbedding[g];

Manipulate[
 Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> 
   AffineTransform[RollPitchYawMatrix[{a, b, c}]][coord]], {a, 0, 
  2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, {c, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Button[ncoord, 
  Set[ncoord, AffineTransform[RollPitchYawMatrix[{a, b, c}]][coord]]]]


When you click ncoord, new coordinates will be stored in ncoord. Then you could do:
Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> ncoord]



Sorry, what is coord in your code. There is no definition in my code, and I didn't get the expected result.

@licheng coord is the coordinate of your graph. I edited answer

Using Heike's ever-useful answer, Extract values for ViewMatrix from a Graphics3D (beware the code overwrites the variable vmat):
n = 8;
k = 4;

ptss = Table[
   Append[#, i] & /@ CirclePoints[{0, 3}, 3, n], {i, 1, k}];
g = Graph[{UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ ptss, 
     UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ Transpose@ptss} // 
    Flatten, VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[ptss, 1]];

(* changes highlighted by comments *)
With[{g = Show[g]}, 
 DynamicModule[{tt, pp, bb, gr, center, scale, v1, vv, theta, phi, 
   alpha, vert, viewAngle}, gr = First@g(****);
  bb = PlotRange[Graphics3D[gr]];
  scale = 1/Abs[#1 - #2] & @@@ bb;
  (*****)
  {vv, center} = ViewVector /. AbsoluteOptions[Show[g], ViewVector];
  v1 = (vv[[1]] - center);
  vert = ViewVertical /. AbsoluteOptions[Show[g], ViewVertical];
  viewAngle = 
   ViewAngle /. AbsoluteOptions[Show[g], ViewAngle] // ReleaseHold // 
    Last;
  (****)
  theta[v1_] := ArcTan[v1[[3]], Norm[v1[[;; 2]]]];
  phi[v1_] := 
   If[Norm[v1[[;; 2]]] > .0001, ArcTan[v1[[1]], v1[[2]]], 0];
  alpha[vert_, v1_] := 
   ArcTan[{-Sin[phi[v1]], Cos[phi[v1]], 0} . vert, 
    Cross[v1/Norm[v1], {-Sin[phi[v1]], Cos[phi[v1]], 0}] . vert];
  tt[v1_, vert_, center_, r_] := 
   TransformationMatrix[
    RotationTransform[-alpha[vert/scale, v1], {0, 0, 1}] . 
     RotationTransform[-theta[v1], {0, 1, 0}] . 
     RotationTransform[-phi[v1], {0, 0, 1}] . 
     ScalingTransform[r {1, 1, 1}] . TranslationTransform[-center]];
  pp[ang_] := {{1, 0, -Tan[ang], 1}, {0, 1, -Tan[ang], 1}, {0, 
     0, -Tan[ang], 0}, {0, 0, -2 Tan[ang], 2}};
  Panel[Column[{Labeled[#, 
        Style["Transforming ViewVector/ViewVertical/ViewAngle to \
ViewMatrix", 15, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold], Top, 
        Background -> White, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray] &@
      Grid[{{Labeled[
          Dynamic@
           Graphics3D[{gr}
            , Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}
            , ViewAngle -> Dynamic[viewAngle]
            , 
            ViewVector -> 
             Dynamic[vv, (vv = #; center = vv[[2]]; 
                v1 = vv[[1]] - center) &]
            , ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vert]
            , ImageSize -> 270], 
          Style["ViewVector, ViewVertical, ViewAngle", 
           FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold], Top, Frame -> True], 
         Labeled[Dynamic@
           Graphics3D[{gr}, 
            ViewMatrix -> {tt[v1, vert, center, 
               Cot[viewAngle/2]/Norm[v1]], pp[viewAngle/2]}, 
            Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
            ImageSize -> 270], 
          Style["ViewMatrix", Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], Top, 
          Frame -> True]}, {Dynamic@
          Labeled[N[{tt[v1, vert, center, Cot[viewAngle/2]/Norm[v1]], 
               pp[viewAngle/2]}] /. {a_?NumericQ :> 
               NumberForm[a, 3]} // 
            MatrixForm[#, TableDirections -> Row] &, 
           Style["ViewMatrix", 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold], 
           Left], SpanFromLeft}}, Spacings -> {1, 2}],
     Button["Print ViewMatrix",
      Print[
       (* Change: store ViewMatrix in vmat *)
       vmat = 
        N[{tt[v1, vert, center, Cot[viewAngle/2]/Norm[v1]], 
          pp[viewAngle/2]}]], ImageSize -> 150]}
    , Alignment -> Left]]]
 ]


Manipulate the graphics on the left. When it looks good, press "Print ViewMatrix". You can copy the output, or I changed the code to store it in vmat. You may want to remove vmat = in the code, if you don't want to risk overwriting vmat.
{t, p} = vmat
(*
{{{0.227867, 0.133103, 0.0234777, -0.458004}, {-0.119583, 0.177096, 
   0.156615, -0.922825}, {0.0629896, -0.145299, 
   0.212395, -0.0950896}, {0., 0., 0., 1.}}, {{1., 0., -0.186964, 
   1.}, {0., 1., -0.186964, 1.}, {0., 0., -0.186964, 0.}, {0., 
   0., -0.373928, 2.}}}
*)

data =PadRight[GraphEmbedding[g], {Automatic, 4}, 1] . 
  Transpose[t] . Transpose[p];
points2D = data[[All, {1, 2}]]/data[[All, 4]]
Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> points2D]


Note that this projects the 3D graph onto 2D, which seemed preferable to me considering the use-case even though it's not what was asked for. You do get what you see, and that's why I would prefer this way.
References

@Heike, Extract values for ViewMatrix from a Graphics3D (answer)
ViewMatrix (the first three points yield the code for data and points2D):

TransformationMatrix and AffineTransformation (on why four components)
Yu-Sung Chang, Extract values for ViewMatrix from a Graphics3D (answer)

Alas, there is no tech note on the View* properties and their relation to screen images that I know of. Aside from studying the documentation for the different options, the best reference is the Q&A with Heike's and Yu-Sung Chang's answers. You can also search the site for the more esoteric options like ViewMatrix, ViewVector, and ViewAngle. These are hardly ever used in ordinary work. ViewPerspective is relatively new solves problems that were rather involved to solve with ViewMatrix.
